# Where to place local dll in a ASP.NET project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, dll, pinvoke

I have a ASP.NET project where I need to pinvoke the following function:

```
[DllImport("NetSh.dll")]
public static extern int RunAsUsr(string pcs_admin, string pcs_user, string pcs_password);
```

The problem is that i get the following exception when I call the function:

> Unable to load DLL 'NetSh.dll': The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

So, where I have to place my dll in order to avoid the exception? At the moment the dll is in the same directory of my `.aspx` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be in `bin` folder in the root of your web app as your .Net assemblies are also located in the `bin` folder.

For web apps `bin` folder is default where .Net will search for files\configs\etc. For windows app it will be the same folder where `exe` app is located.

Answer (score 1):

By default you should put in the Bin folder of your project. if for some reason you do not want it there you could also specify a path for the DLL in the DLLIMPORT statement.